# Performing a t-test with discrete (currency) data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions, discrete-data

I want to perform a 2 sample t-test assuming unequal variances, however my variable is currency. Currency is discrete, however when checking the assumptions of the t-test, I see that the data should be continuous.

Technically, they aren't continuous, but I guess it's closer to a ratio scale (maybe interval). Is this assumption violated? What else should I check?

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: n=24 for both variables.

Comment: What do they look like (within the groups)? Are they vaguely normal looking?

Comment: I ran a JB test, they both appear normal.

Comment: What do you precisely mean by your "variable is currency." As in, your variable is measured in dollars and there cannot be fractions of a cent (discrete units are $1/100$ of a dollar)? And you're trying to compare the mean of two samples?

Comment: Yes, dollars and cents only. No fractional values less than 1 cent.

Comment: Unless the prices are 5 cents, 2 cents, etc..., that's getting a bit pedantic. Do what @gung suggests to check normality, and if it looks good, you're fine. If it's somewhat off with right skew, another thing to check might be log normality: that comes up a lot in economic situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Discrete isn't continuous, so technically the assumption of the t-test is not met, and that's that.  However, the t-test is fairly robust and having $N=48$ with equal groups is a decent sample, so it might be OK.  After all, in practice all data are discrete at some level because we don't record data to infinite decimal places.

I would *look* (i.e., plot; cf. [R - QQPlot: how to see whether data are normally distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/52293/) & [How to interpret a QQ plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/101274/)) at your data to see if they appear reasonably normal and meet the other assumptions (e.g., homoscedasticity).  I would *not* run formal tests for normality (cf. [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/)).  If they look 'close enough', you're probably OK.

On the other hand, it is generally considered sub-optimal to follow the procedure 'check assumptions, if OK, run test'.  If you think this might be a problem, you can just go straight to a more robust option.  (Cf. [How to choose between t-test or non-parametric test e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/121852/).)

Comment: Worth pointing out too that with more data, he could lean on asymptotic arguments. Under certain regularity conditions, the sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$ would converge to a normally distributed random variable even if $x$ were discrete.