# Why do my histogram look normal, however the Shapiro-Wilk normality test indicate non-normality?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I want to check if one of the columns in my dataframe "Activity_Sleep" is normally distributed.  According  to the histogram it normally distributed:

```
Minutes_active <- hist(activity_sleep$sedentary_minutes, 
     border="light blue", 
     col="blue", 
     las=1, 
     breaks=5)
```

[image: RPlot]

The Shapiro test however, gives the following results:

```
Shapiro.test(activity_sleep$sedentary_minutes)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  activity_sleep$sedentary_minutes
W = 0.95241, p-value = 5.604e-10 .
```

According to this result, the p-value is extremely small and the null hypothesis, i.e. that the distribution is normal, needs to be rejected.
Why do I get two contrary results?

Comment: Your distribution looks more sharply peaked than a classic normal distribution. Try visualizing it with finer bins.

Comment: A histogram with 8 breaks might be a bad tool to assess for normality.
Shapiro test is also bad for assessing normality, too powerful on large sample sizes. Best practice is to check in details your data with QQplot and other tools.

Comment: SW test is very sensitive to deviations from normality, especially as your sample size increased. You're better off using a qqnorm/qqplot. See https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2019/02/09/what-have-i-got-against-the-shapiro-wilk-test/

Comment: Check this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52293/r-qqplot-how-to-see-whether-data-are-normally-distributed?rq=1

Comment: What is your sample size? Please tell us (as an edit to the post). Also, redo the histogram with more bins, or better, show us a qq-plot

Comment: @Kjetil You can accurately estimate the sample size by reading the values on the vertical axis.

Comment: All of these are good *answers*, or at least components of an answer ...

Comment: @jdobres If the mean of the normal distribution was say about $700$ and the standard deviation about $120$ you might get something like that histogram shape.  As you say, finer bins would help

Comment: In short, you are comparing a very loose visual test ("does it seem normal to me?") with a very demanding numerical test.

Comment: Are the sedentary_minutes rounded to the nearest 30 minutes? It looks like it, judging from the histogram.